# Opening and closing braces issue

Tags: .net, select, razor, umbraco, renderpartial

I can't figure out this error while my all parenthesis are correctly closed.

[image: The error]

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste the text rather than using a screenshot. I had to type out what you had to replicate this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. You are already in a code block, so you don't need to use `@:`.
2. You need to double-up on the `{ }` since you are initializing an object (`ViewDataDictionary`) that is a collection of more objects (`KeyValuePair<string, object>`).
3. [`RenderPartial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) does not return a string. Use [`@Html.Partial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) instead.

```
<select id="multiselect" name="Checkbox"
     onChange="@Html.Partial("GalleryListing", new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData) { { "param1", this.Value } })">
```